# Orderby custom product Query like in Woocommerce Backend product list

Tags: php, database, sorting, woocommerce, product

I have a query that pulls products from Woocommerce on a special page depending on selections from the user. It works but they're out of order.

You can drag products around in the admin (Products) and it changes the display order on the normal front end store. Where is this order stored in the database so I can order my query results to match this order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is about the `orderby` argument used in the main default query **which is `menu_order`** column and `post_title` column as second sorting argument both located in `wp_posts` database table, for "product" `post_type` column.

---

Some related threads to alter the product order in frontend:

- [Sort Woocommerce products catalog to alphabetical desc order by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54050418/sort-woocommerce-products-catalog-to-alphabetical-desc-order-by-default/54050868#54050868)
- [Add a new custom default ordering catalog option in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52273655/add-a-new-custom-default-ordering-catalog-option-in-woocommerce/52275842#52275842)
- [Set custom product sorting as default Woocommerce sorting option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53589711/set-custom-product-sorting-as-default-woocommerce-sorting-option/53589762#53589762)

Comment: This is what I thought it would be. But the menu_order values of the products are either 0 or 1. Surely there's something else to distinguish order between two dozen products?

Comment: @dstana I have updated my answer… First sorting argument is "menu_order" and second sorting "argument is "post_title"…